# How to run a command or execute script in remote machine using puppet bolt?

Tags: puppet, puppet-bolt

I'm trying to execute a command in remote machine using **puppet bolt** but I'm getting below errors in powershell.

```
bolt command run "Get-Process" --nodes winrm://localhost --no-ssl
```

**Error :**

> Unknown argument '--nodes'

```
bolt command run 'uname -a' --targets 192.168.0.145
```

**Error:**

> Failed on 192.168.0.140:
>   Timeout after 10 seconds connecting to 192.168.0.140
>   Failed on 1 target: 192.168.0.140
>   Failed on 192.168.0.140:
>   Timeout after 10 seconds connecting to 192.168.0.140
>   Failed on 1 target: 192.168.0.140

How to fix above issues

Answer (score 1):

Appears the current version changed "--nodes" to "--targets"